# how to do fine-tuning with resnet50 model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, resnet

I have seen many examples in the Internet about how to fine tune VGG16 and InceptionV3.For example, some people will set the first 25 layers to be frozen when fine tuning VGG16. For InceptionV3, the first 172 layers will be frozen. But how about resnet? When we do fine tuning, we will freeze some layers of the base model, like follows:

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50

base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=(input_dim, input_dim, channels))

..............

for layer in base_model.layers[:frozen_layers]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

So how should I set the frozen_layers? Actually I do not know how many layers should I set to be frozen when I do fine-tuning with VGG16, VGG19, ResNet50, InceptionV3 .etc. Can anyone give me suggestions on how to fine tune these models? Especially how many layers people will freeze when they do fine tuning with these models?

Comment: I have also heard that if we only train our own dense layers, it's called transfer learning. And if we train some layers in the base_model(like resnet, vgg .etc) with a small learning rate, it's called fine-tuning. I know the convolutional blocks have some special meaning, so how to freeze the layers in the base model in order to do fine-tuning?

Comment: I see these on this blog: [building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's curious.... the VGG16 model has a total of 23 layers... (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/vgg16.py)

---

All these models have a similar strucutre:

- A series of convolutional layers
- Followed by a few dense layers

These few dense layers are what keras calls `top`. (As in the `include_top` parameter).

Usually, this fine tuning happens only in the last dense layers. You let the convolutional layers (which understand images and locate features) do their job unchanged, and create your ou top part adapted to your personal classes.

People often create their own top part because they don't have exactly the same classes the original model was trained to. So they adapt the final part, and train only the final part.

So, you create a model with `include_top=False`, then you freeze it entirely.
Now you add your own dense layers and leave these trainable.

This is the most usual adaptation of these models.

For other kinds of fine tuning, there probably aren't clear rules.

Comment: Sorry for that vgg mistake. I mean people will freeze the vgg network except for the last convolutional block in order to be more adapted to their own data, and then tune the last convolutional block as well as the dense layers with a small learning rate, like this: [vgg16 fine-tuning](https://blog.keras.io/img/imgclf/vgg16_modified.png)